# filter text file having particular word

Tags: asp.net, file, filtering

I have text file containing hundreds of rows I want to to filters row of having word "rip" and put them in another text file.in asp.net.

is is possible can I achieve this.please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string[] allLines=File.ReadAllLines("yourFilepath");  
StringBuilder newFile=new StringBuilder();
foreach(string line in allLines)  
{  
    if(line.Contains("rip"))  
     newFile.AddLine(line);  
}  
File.WriteAllText("newPath",newFile.ToString());
```

Answer (score 3):

if you want filter without code directly you can try this

Go to Search menu > Find... > Select "Mark" Tab. Activate regular expressions. Search for "rip". Don't forget to check "Bookmark lines" and Press "Mark All"

==> All Rows you want to keep got a Bookmark
Go to Menu "Search - Bookmark - Inverse Bookmark"

==> All Line you want to delete are bookmarked.
Go to Menu "Search - Bookmark - Remove Bookmarked lines"

==> All Bookmarked lines are deleted.